# Is there a name for the interval [1: 5/2]

Tags: chord-theory, intervals

I was looking at intervals here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pitch_intervals
and I noticed that they are all contained in the octave [1: 2]

How does one talk about something like [1: 5/2]?

Comment: That'd be an octave plus a perfect fifth.

Comment: Ok so you just combine the names of intervals to go out past the octave?

Comment: It depends, you can also call it a perfect twelfth. See this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)#Compound_intervals

Comment: @KeizerHarm It's not a perfect twelfth or an "octave plus a perfect fifth" because the ratios multiply.  A perfect twelfth would be 2 × (3/2) = 3.  (Or [1 : 3] using the inverted form in the question.]

Comment: @Theodore Ok, my bad ^^; OP please discount everything I said

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you're describing the intervals in their inverse.  An octave is usually written (including within the Wikipedia article you linked) as the ratio **2 : 1**.  It may also be written as the improper fraction **2/1**.

When combining smaller intervals, the ratios *multiply* to reach the total.

The particular interval you mention, **5 : 2**  or **5/2** can be considered as (**2/1**) × (**5/4**), which is to say an octave plus a just major third, also known as a just [major 10th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_(chord)#Tenth).

Comment: Side note (obvious to most of us :-) ) is that adding named intervals requires subtracting "one."  In this case octave (8) plus fifth (5) produces  twelfth (8 + 5 -1 ).   In math we call this something like the "fence post theory" because you don't want to count the point which is the  end of one sequence  *and* the beginning of the next one twice.